# Dynamic designing of li elements in angular 4

Tags: css, angular

I am fetching a data from api and i am showing the result in li elements. The data coming is an array of object which has name and size . i want to design the li elements according to the size . How it can be done in angular 4 ?

Comment: You're looking for `*ngClass` https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either write your own oderBy pipe or you can may be use  https://github.com/danrevah/ngx-pipes#orderby?

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize `ngClass` directive or class bindings `[class.class-name]="booleanExpression"`

```
<li
    *ngFor="let item of data"
    [class.item-big]="item.size === 'big'"
    [class.item-small]="item.size === 'small'">
    <!-- ... -->
</li>
```

or

```
<li
    *ngFor="let item of data"
    [ngClass]="{
        'item-big': item.size === 'big',
        'item-small': item.size === 'small'
    }">
    <!-- ... -->
</li>
```

More on that [here](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles)